# What is the purpose of uplifting in "Orion’s Arm?"

Tags: orions-arm

In the [Orion’s Arm](https://www.orionsarm.com/) sci-fi project, one of the most notable features is “proactive evolution”, or provolution, which involves raising animals (and even plants) to sapience through genetic engineering and cyborgisation. This concept, (more broadly known as uplifting) appears in many works of sci-fi, but generally it is to create servant races or purely out of curiosity whereas the beings in Orion’s Arm seem to do this for neither reason.

Considering the expense involved in bringing up a whole new race, I struggle to think of a reason that makes this worthwhile. Why do they do this?

Comment: If you haven't, you should surely read David Brin's Uplift novels -- nine of them, as I recall.  They had a non-economic reason to maintain the cycle of uplift.

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed directly on the Orion's Arm Encyclopedia Galactica website under the heading **[Provolution](https://www.orionsarm.com/eg-topic/45bbfdbc381f4)**.

A range of reasons are mooted; scientific curiosity, the development of slave races (albeit rarely), for weird religious reasons, for artistic purposes, out of philanthropy and as the species equivalent of '*because it gives us something to do*'.

> Ever since the middle Information Age, Terragen civilization has shown
> a great enthusiasm for provolution. In part this is an aspect of the
> transhuman and extropian (and later) ideals of maximization of
> intelligence and awareness for all, rather than for a privileged few,
> but it has also been suggested transapients encourage the practice as
> a way of giving ordinary sophonts a challenge and sense of purpose
> that might otherwise be lacking in many autotopic societies. Although
> many sophonts are happy to pursue other hobbies and interests, there
> are others who actually need to be given something to do that appears
> to have high significance, so they can have a sense of fulfilment and
> purpose in life. Provolution is perfect for these people. It is a
> deeply inspiring task — bringing intelligence and culture to a new
> race — so it naturally fulfilling. It is also incredibly
> time-consuming and labour-intensive, since the species being provolved
> requires constant attention and empathetic connection, and since this
> project may extend over many generations of creatures, a whole sophont
> lifespan. Thus it is one of the few tasks in the modern galaxy that is
> rarely left to automation, (beyond ancillary use for design and
> physical care). For this reason provolution projects are a source of
> pride among many sophont clades. Another significant difference
> between a provolution project and any other common hobby is the level
> of legal oversight and regulation. Given that provolution will lead to
> a sophont species the ethics and laws around sophont rights are
> intimately involved. Very often an individual or group wishing to
> embark on such a project must apply for a licence, writ or other form
> of permission from a relevant governing body/transapient. If the
> proposal is approved the angelnet (or other suitable monitoring
> infrastructure) will be used to ensure compliance on behalf of the
> provolver. Some polities have even stricter rules requiring a
> mandatory period of aftercare, be it pastoral, scientific or economic,
> to ensure that the provolved population is not abandoned before their
> time. Many polities subscribe to the "handover" method in which
> members of the provolved species must be given a position of authority
> within the project before it is complete so that they might guide its
> progress towards completion. This latter consideration has led to many
> projects moving in directions their originators had not intended. Much
> to the ire of the authenticist, fictionalist and castelist schools the
> second order effects of a developing provolve culture can lead to
> unexpected behaviours and even physiology as the clade seeks to
> redesign itself.